# Sublime Text 3 giving error while compiling C program

Tags: c++, c

so im facing problem in using sublime. I m using dev c++ as compiler and i have included its bin folder path in Environment Variables I'm using a lapbook and 32 bit Dev c++ and its working fine but when I try to compile my program in Sublime it is giving me error.

`This version of C:\Users\Paras Ghai\Documents\Sublime.c\NumPyramid.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher.`

The path of bin folder of dev c++ in my device is :

> C:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin

I don't know what to do. Should I do changes in my built system or something.

Comment: Try CodeLite IDE for programming why sublime editor.

Comment: So It works when you compile with Dev C++ but not when you compile the same code from Sublime 3?  That is definitely the compiler flags because it is the same compiler and the same code.  Where do you tell Sublime 3 what compiler flags you are using?

Comment: Sorry what are compiler flags im mediator in programming so I dont know about them so much

Answer (score 1):

There could be two reasons behind this issue:

1. **The file architecture is incompatible with your system arch:**

   There are two types of computer architecture, 32-bit and 64-bit. If this problem belong to file incompatibility with Windows, then it clearly means that you're running a 64-bit executable in a 32-bit machine.

   Here, as you've added that your machine runs in 32-bit arch, try checking your compilation options.
2. **The file is incompatible with your Windows:**

   If you're still having this issue, you should check if that binary file supports running on your corresponding Windows. Because I've seen that when you run latest software programs in older Windows (like Win XP, etc.) or vice versa, you get compatibility error.

   Thus, you can use the compatibility troubleshooter from:

   ```
   File Properties → Compatibility → Run compatibility troubleshooter
   ```

   to detect a compatible environment and downgrade the compatibility mode.

Comment: Hi I troubleshooted the dev c++ and I have seen that I have set 32 bit release in Dev c++
but it didnot work it gave me the same error and I have Window 10

Comment: @LovishGarg Try uninstalling the Dev-C++ with its settings from `%AppData%`, `%LocalAppData%` & `ProgramData` and install it again.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think that the problem was that Dev-C++ was using MinGW 64 bit compiler but it is weird that if by mistake I have downloaded a 64bit application on my 32 bit arch then too it is running so.

> C:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin

Above I saw 64 After MinGW so I unistalled it and then intall just MinGW basic bin for my C programming and then the path was->

> C:\MinGW\bin

Above shows that Dev-C++ was using 64 bit MinGW compiler.
But that 64 bit compiler can't integrate with my *`cmd`* and It throw an error.